# where the commenting is removed during the program devolopment in c

Tags: c++, c, linux, comments

I added comments in the program.

In which step it will be removed during devolopment like compiling, linking ,loading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's specified as happening during phase 3 of translation (§:2.2/1):

> 3 - The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (2.5) and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. **Each comment is replaced by one space character.**

[emphasis added]

Answer (score 6):

Lexically, they are ignored since scanning (lexical analysis).

Previously, I was fooled by the following fact: if you have debug symbol generation enabled,  and the source is still there you can see them in `gdb` or`objdump`:

```
00000000004004ec <main>:
int main()
{
  4004ec:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ed:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    /* This is just a comment */
    return 0;
  4004f0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  4004f5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004f6:   c3                      retq   
  4004f7:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4004fe:   00 00
```

From code

```
int main()
{
    /* This is just a comment */
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc -g -O0 1.c` and obtained via `objdump -CDgS a.out`. That is because those tools read the source file if it finds it and correlate debug info found in the binary file to the content of the source file via the line numbers.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The comments do not end up in the final executable, even if it is compiled with `-g`.  What objdump does is it finds the source file and, using the line number information from the debug symbols in the executable, it includes code and comments from the original source file.

To convince yourself, try renaming 1.c -- objdump will no longer display source and comments, only disassembly.  To further convince yourself, change the contents of 1.c and objdump will be 'fooled'.  For a final test, run strace on objdump to see that it opens and reads 1.c.

Comment: Fixed now, hopefully :)

Answer (score 2):

They are removed during pre-compilation(lexical analysis phase) time as it is when the intermediate code is generated and there, comments are not needed.

Comment: Isn't it pre-compilation!?

Answer (score 0):

The lexical analysis phase of the compilation process removes the comments in your program. Lexical analysis is also called scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are ignored from the input string in by the lexical analysis part of the compilation process.

If you want to use program comments for any purpose, you have to write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say comments are removed.
It is better to say comments are skipped by parser during compilation.

Parser is a program which start reading your C code written in english and convert it to Assembly code. The parser program just read your code written in english and skip the sentences which starts with "/*" or "//".

So comments are not removed they exist in your C code but skipped by compiler to create assembly file.